# ReinforcementLearning.jl crashes: MethodError: no method matching length(::Nothing)

Tags: deep-learning, julia, reinforcement-learning

My Julia Version is 1.10.1. After installung ReinforcementLearning.jl I tried to run the example:

[https://juliareinforcementlearning.org/docs/experiments/experiments/DQN/JuliaRL_BasicDQN_CartPole/#JuliaRL\\_BasicDQN\\_CartPole](https://juliareinforcementlearning.org/docs/experiments/experiments/DQN/JuliaRL_BasicDQN_CartPole/#JuliaRL%5C%5C_BasicDQN%5C%5C_CartPole)

Issuing:

```
ex = E`JuliaRL_BasicDQN_CartPole
```

results in the output:

```
BasicDQN <-> CartPole
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
typename(Experiment)
├─ policy => typename(Agent)
│  ├─ policy => typename(QBasedPolicy)
...
```

Then issuing:

```
run(ex)
```

I get the error message:

```
  BasicDQN <-> CartPole
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Nothing)

Closest candidates are:
  length(::Base.MethodSpecializations)
   @ Base reflection.jl:1166
  length(::IRTools.Inner.Block)
   @ IRTools ~/.julia/packages/IRTools/Q1Ewy/src/ir/ir.jl:559
  length(::CUDA.NVML.DeviceIterator) (method too new to be called from this world context.)
   @ CUDA ~/.julia/packages/CUDA/BbliS/lib/nvml/device.jl:45
  ...

Stacktrace:
  [1] #s597#122
    @ ~/.julia/packages/GPUCompiler/S3TWf/src/cache.jl:18 [inlined]
  [2] var"#s597#122"(f::Any, tt::Any, ::Any, job::Any)
    @ GPUCompiler ./none:0
  [3] (::Core.GeneratedFunctionStub)(::UInt64, ::LineNumberNode, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ Core ./boot.jl:602
  [4] cached_compilation(cache::Dict{…}, job::GPUCompiler.CompilerJob, compiler::typeof(CUDA.cufunction_compile), linker::typeof(CUDA.cufunction_link))
 ...
```

Elsewhere I fouind the assumption that this kind of error could be due to an outdated version of GPUCompiler. The version installed = "0.17.3", the now stable version is "0.26.1".

How to resolve this?